# How to get access to the beta features of Trello

Tags: trello

If we check the Trello [development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c), there are features that are in Limited Distribution list.

Can we get access to those features while still in beta? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reopened the signup card for early access: https://trello.com/card/i-want-early-access/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1335